# Checkboxes need to be checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I have checkboxes and I need them to be keep their status (checked or unchecked) after refreshing the page until user change the status.
This is the code I have:

```
<%  @album.audios.each do |audio| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,nil,class: "song"%>
<% end %>
```

I am stuck with this. What is the better way to do this? Shall I use sessions here?

Comment: @Maddy It has to be "I", not "i" when someone tells about himself.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing nil in place of checked in your view code. You should pass true for checked element and false for non checked elements.

```
<% for audio in @album.audios %>
  <%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,(true/false),class: "song"%>
<% end %>
```

Below is syntax for checkbox tag :

```
check_box_tag( name, value, checked, html_and_other_options)
```

Comment: You should also be using `.each` instead of `for`. Just a Ruby best practice :)

Comment: Sorry I am looking for the checkboxes to stay on their status(checked or unchecked) If the web page refreshes also.....

Comment: You can iterate values from your db in this case.

Comment: Thats a good idea but db entry for each clicking means it will be not good practice yes?....I am looking for a client side solution (javascript or sessions )....

Comment: If you want to save checked values although user refresh page then you need to update record in db on check and uncheck of checkbox field using ajax. And iterate checked values from db

Comment: Then go for session. Javascript values get refresh after page refresh but session persist. And clear session values on redirect. And update session value using javascript inside view will help you

Comment: Ok, But I am just a beginner I cant able to go through this is there any references regarding this method which you told?

Comment: Try coockie very easy to maintain http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist the status of your checkbox, you'll either need to set the data in a [`session`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html), or somehow tie it into the `ActiveRecord object` for your form.

I'll detail about the form first...

---

**Form**

Your current setup is that you are using [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

You must know the difference between `form_tag` and `form_for` is that the former has *independent* data, whilst the latter's data is from an ActiveRecord object. The issue for a lot of people is because they don't know the difference, they will likely be confused with how to implement either method, which could be an issue here.

I would recommend using `form_for`:

```
#app/views/albums/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <% @album.audios.each do |audio| %>
     <%= fields_for 'audio[]', audio do |audio_fields| -%>
        <%= audio_fields.check_box nil %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Great reference here: [Syntax for form_for when building an array from checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850188/syntax-for-form-for-when-building-an-array-from-checkboxes)

Another method could be [`collection_check_boxes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes):

```
#app/views/albums/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select_boxes :audio_ids, @album.audios, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The important thing to note about this "method" is that since the values of the checkboxes are tied in directly with your `@album` ActiveRecord object, it gives you the ability to "persist" the data by saving it to the database.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with the current setup, but to persist the data - even between views - you need to ensure you have some place where you can keep the data stored (either the DB or something like a cookie)

---

**Sessions**

Sessions would be a logical choice for this, although as you have not stated what you're looking to achieve, I don't know where they'll fit in.

If your form is to be "submitted", you'll be able to set the "session" cookies of your data in the controller action to which you send your request. For example, if you send the request to `albums#update`, you're going to want to store the session in that action:

```
#app/views/albums/edit.html.erb 
<%  @album.audios.each do |audio| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]", audio.id, session[:album_ids][audio.id], class: "song"%>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      session[:album_ids] = params[:album_ids]

      @album = Album.find params[:id]
      @album.audios.each do |audio|
          session[:album_ids][audio.id] = params[:album_ids][audio.id]
      end
   end
end
```

---

**Stateless**

Finally, you'll want to look into the workings of a ["stateless"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) protocol (of which HTTP is very much one). This is important because by being "stateless", an application doesn't have any bearing on where or when the data was submitted - in essence it treats each resource as an individual.

The issue you have is that you have to *persist* your data - which can only happen if you have a way to match the user's identity (session) with the data they've either submitted, or wanting to retrieve.

In your case, you'll want to look for at either using a `session` cookie, or ActiveRecord object to persist the data you submit.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer in this link I have given my detailed need plese see that too thank you Rich Peck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930992/music-player-select-some-songs-and-play-in-rails