# Music Player select some songs and play in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jplayer

In my rails 4 application I have jplayer to play music files , its works fine and I need to add select some songs from playlist using check-box and play option ,Its harder to customize the default jplayer playlist so that I have created a separate playlist and the code is

```
  <%= form_tag album_path , method: :get,  id: "sel" do  %>
     <%= submit_tag "play", name: nil, :class => "btn btn-success " %>
     <%= link_to "Play All", album_path , :class => "btn btn-success "%>
      <%  @album.audios.each do |audio| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,nil,class: "song"%></td>
        <%= link_to audio.name, album_path(id: @album.id, audio_ids: audio) %>
        <%= audio.artist %>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

and its works fine too Whenever I choose some check-boxes the corresponding  ids passing and I will render json according to that and I will create playlist and this is code for creating code in jplayer

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url:window.location ,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
       $.each(json,function(data){ 
        myPlaylist.add({title:$(this).attr("name"), artist:$(this).attr("artist"), m4a:$(this).attr("audio_url")});
         });
          }
       });
```

Now I need is the check-boxes to be keep their status (checked or unchecked) after refreshing the page until user change the status. How to do this one?......Whether I can use sessions?
(If there is any way of having jplayer default playlist check-boxes say me that too )....

Comment: You mention you're refreshing the page, yet you're using Ajax. Can you detail the process which would lead to the page refreshing?

Comment: The updation of songs done only after refreshing the web page so I have put all those codes in $(window).load(function(){{);

Comment: Yes, which I'm guessing will load the ajax functionality? That would mean you wouldn't be refreshing the page?

Comment: the ajax function goes inside the window.load function

Comment: hmm okay, so you're loading ajax from `window.load`? Can you explain it further - I really don't get your structure here

Comment: Dear rich, If you get some time can you take me to a chat box please, my reputation not allow me to create chat box, I will elaborate briefly what I have done and what I am stucks