# Creating a filter for active record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Just started coding in Ruby on Rails and have managed to create the basic CRUD functionality for my app.

I can also list them all.
Now I would like to create a filter for the user to interact with.

```
Database Schema
create_table "nades", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.integer   "grenade"
   t.text     "description"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "map_id"
end
```

The "grenade" can have a value from 1-4, corresponding to a specific grenade:

`[[1,"smoke"], [2,"flash"], [3,"molotov"], [4,"he-grande"]`

Now I'm trying to create a filter with 4 buttons in the view. Where you can toggle each nade on/off to show or hide them in the results.

`[x]Smoke [ ]Flash [ ]Moltov [x]HE`

This should only return the nades `where grenade = [1,4]`

After some reading it looks like scoped would be nice to use to manage this.
However I'm not sure how to make it work as I want.

Was thinking of doing something like:

`scope :by_nade, -> grenade { where(grenade: grenade) if status.grenade? }`

However this only allows me to get 1 specific nade type from the database.
Is it posible to send multiple parameters like:

`http://localhost:3000/nades/?by_nade=1,2  ??`

Or is it a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into creating a form with an array of options (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850188/syntax-for-form-for-when-building-an-array-from-checkboxes)).  That will allow you to get multiple values for the specific type of grenade.

Your scope will work with either a single id *or* an array of ids and using the array of options approach should yield an array that will work.  In your example above it would effectively be Nade.by_grenade([1,4]).  You might want to guard against the array being empty (assuming that an empty list would be a bad thing).

Comment: I gues I would have to create a model for the 'grenade' to make this form?

Comment: Figuered out how to make the form with the option as an array :)